# Importing specific cells from an Excel file into MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

We are currently using a simulation package that outputs data to an Excel spreadsheet. The output cannot be customized to the level that fits the company standards. The good news is that the spreadsheet's format is locked. And the data I need is located in (15) different cells that are scattered all over the spreadsheet. (If they were in a column it'd be easy)

I would like to write a VB app in MS Access that would open the file, look at 15 different cells, and then import the data in these cells to a specific field in a table. From there I an do anything I want with the data. But while I'm fairly confident in my abilities with access, I'm having a hard time coming up with code for do what I want to do

The 15 pieces of data I need reside in the cells BU22, X38, X41, AX38, AX41, BW38, Q49, Q54, Q61, Q69, Q74, BP68, V86, BH81, & BI84

From what I understand I can use the ws.Range method like this:

```
Dim strSecondValue as String
strSecondValue=ws.Range ("BU22")
```

Getting that info from the excel cell to the MS Access table is proving to be difficult.

Any help here?

Comment: Does it work in Excel like you intend? What exactly is causing the difficulty?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. The simulation outputs an excel file in a format that is not suitable for a formal report. It's unorganized and scattered. We have a formal report template that we want it to look like. We'd like it so that the user can Start MS Access, run a program, browse to the data file and that program will take the data from the cells and import it into a table. From there I can query the table and have the results go right into a report that is formatted the way we want. All the user needs to do is print to a PDF and we're done.

Answer (score 1):

External data sources can queried in few different ways.

```
SELECT * FROM 
[Sheet1$A1:A1], 
[Sheet1$B2:B2] 
IN 'C:\Book1.xlsx'[Excel 12.0; Hdr=No]
```

To specify field names:

```
select A.F1 as A1, B.F1 as B2 from 
[Sheet1$A1:A1] as A, 
[Sheet1$B2:B2] as B
in 'C:\Book1.xlsx'[Excel 12.0; Hdr=No]
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177907

Comment: Thank you for your response. I believe that the snippets of code you are posting are SQL. If that is correct, then I'm pretty sure that I cannot use it. I am writing this in VBA through MS Access. But I understand what you are trying to tell me. I just need a way to do it within MS Access and VBA

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this.

```
Sub ImportDataFromRange()
' Delete any previous access table, otherwise the next line will add an additional table
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "ExcelRange"
' Import data from Excel using a static range
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "ExcelStaticRangeData", "C:\your_path_here\ExcelSample.xls", True, "Sheet1!A1:J20"
End Sub    

Private Sub Command0_Click()
   ImportDataFromRange
End Sub
```